# what is $\mathrm{Res}_{E/F}(\mathbb{G}_m)/\mathbb{G}_m $?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, algebraic-groups

In general, what is the algebaic group $\mathbb{G}_m$ ? However I am looking in the textbook it says:
$$ \mathrm{Res}_{E/F}(\mathbb{G}_m) \,/\, \mathbb{G}_m $$
where $E$ is an extension of $F$ with $[E:F] = n$.  And the book calls this a **torus**.

The answer might appear in this book of [David Witte Morris](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063) which is 600 pages.  I found many instances of the word "torus" but none with the blackboard $\mathbb{G}$.

Comment: $\Bbb G_m :=\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$ with designated maps induced by $\mu : \Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$ given by $x\mapsto x\otimes x$, $\epsilon : \Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to\Bbb Z$ given by $x\mapsto 1$, and $\iota : \Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$ given by $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ (you can base change this to any field you like). A torus is an algebraic group over a field $k$ which becomes isomorphic to a product of $\Bbb G_m$'s when you base change to $\overline{k}$.

Comment: @Stahl what do the points in $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[x, x^{-1}]$ look like?   By [spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring) I guess you mean the **prime** ideals?  When I think of torus I think of diagonal matrices:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 
e^{i\theta_1} &  &  & 0  \\ 
 & e^{i\theta_2} &  &  \\
& & \dots &  \\
0 & & & e^{i\theta_n} \end{array} \right] $$
as would be the case in the unitary group.

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is the set of prime ideals of $R$ with the Zariski topology. $\Bbb G_m$ is geometrically just $\Bbb A^1$ without $\{0\}$ (over whatever base), but of course it also has a group scheme structure.

Comment: A torus can be more complicated over a non-algebraically closed base, but if you're working over an algebraically closed field, your intuition of diagonal matrices is right, although you want to allow matrices of the form $\left( \begin{array}{cccc} \alpha &  &  &  \\   & \beta &  &  \\ & & \ddots  \\  & & & \gamma \end{array} \right)$, where $\alpha,\beta,\dots,\gamma\in \overline{k}^\times$, not just things of the form $e^{i\theta}$ (which doesn't make sense over arbitrary fields anyway).

Comment: @Stahl I think a reasonable example is $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ so that $[E:F]=2$ but there still can be a torus.

Comment: See the answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7715/what-is-restriction-of-scalars-for-a-torus) for more information